# Netbeans displays files as ignored, but they're not in gitignore

Tags: git, netbeans, gitignore

Netbeans displays one folder and all underlying files as ignored by VCS (I use Git), but when I use `git status` or Atlassian SourceTree the files are not ignored and listed as changed and ready for commit.

Specifically NetBeans IDE 7.1 (Build 201112071828) - PHP build, Git plugin version: 1.1.1.1 (shipped with NetBeans IDE 7.1 (Build 201112071828)), CLI git version 1.7.5.4

The ignored folder is `www/inc` . Unignoring doesn't help. Ignoring and unignoring again changes the `.gitignore` file accordingly, but the folder is still displayed grey with `(I)` - the ignored status marker. Also I've noticed some buggy behavior: subfolders of `www/inc` often turn grey only if I unfold them to see their content, but sometimes they turn grey when I unfold the already grey `www/inc`.

I checked `.gitignore` in the top project folder and all the way to ignored one and in the whole project source tree. There's only one file and it states

```
/nbproject/private/
/log/
/www/debuglogs/*.log
/www/images/goods/*/*
/www/inc/content/
```

The `.git/config` file doesn't contain any mentions of ignoring. In `~/.gitconfig` global gitignore is defined as `/Users/sheershoff/.gitignore_global` and the global ignore file is the following:

```
*~
.DS_Store
```

There's no `.git/info` folder in local Git repository, and the remote bare repository has the `project.git/info/exclude` file, but it consists of several commented out lines, which, I believe, are default.

Concerning Netbeans, I tried cleaning out cache folder and setting global IDE ignored files settings (`Tools->Options->Miscellaneous->Files`) to an empty string and restarting the IDE. Also I checked project ignored folders settings - it is empty.

After hours of resultless but effortful digging and googling I managed to resolve similar problem on Windows machine (same Netbeans build number) with the same project pulled from the same remote repo with the same folder disrespectfully ignored by editing some Netbeans properties files (should I mention the `ignore.path` setting is empty here and was empty there on Windows, and I also set all the includes settings to empty strings since I don't use them in the project). And as far as I can remember, it was something with **includes** section, not with **ignore** section. Though, can't find it in the repo history, probably it was in the private netbeans project settings or some global netbeans settings.

And now this bug repeats on my Mac machine at work and nothing helps me to make Netbeans show the not ignored files as not ignored.

What should I do to make them displayed normal in Netbeans, as they're not ignored according to other Git tools?

Comment: I've reported this behavior as a [bug to Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=208984)

Answer (score 1):

As of newest builds, removing the line `/www/images/goods/*/*` will resolve the issue.